Unity burst compiler error related to Android build and Unity-google-ads
My unity project was building and running but I added google ads and now the app is not building. Everytime I hit build button it shows an error that links to a line that says following:
#if UNITY_2022_2_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID
            if (settings.targetPlatform == TargetPlatform.Android)
            {
                // Enable Armv9 security features (PAC/BTI) if needed
                settings.aotSettingsForTarget.EnableArmv9SecurityFeatures = PlayerSettings.Android.enableArmv9SecurityFeatures;
                if (PlayerSettings.Android.enableArmv9SecurityFeatures)
                {
                    settings.extraOptions.Add(GetOption(OptionPlatformConfiguration, "armv9-sec")); //<- this line 
                }
            }
#endif

Error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor.DoSetup (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.11/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:274)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor.PrepareOnMainThread (UnityEditor.Build.IGenerateNativePluginsForAssemblies+PrepareArgs args) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.11/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:137)
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.GetGenerateNativePluginsForAssembliesSettings (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <2d8ca4eb2ddd452d9e2715b1b5605cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PlayerBuildConfigFor (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <2d8ca4eb2ddd452d9e2715b1b5605cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor+<GetDataForBuildProgramFor>d__57.MoveNext () (at <2d8ca4eb2ddd452d9e2715b1b5605cbb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor+<GetDataForBuildProgramFor>d__34.MoveNext () (at <7e15d46f898a4082b7f6f54d49c06f6a>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext () (at <9d6264b087384274846c7c1593e04f5a>:0)
     ...

I do not need any armV9 feature. I just want it to work for armv7 and 64.
I have deleted Library folder several times. But the error is persistent.
Using Unity 2023.2.5f1 and burst compiler is 1.8.11.
I need to know what I should do, remove ads or downgrade Unity version or something else.
